# How do I retrieve a key from a JSON response, when I don't know the key value?

Tags: javascript, json

This may be really simple, but I've beat my head against the wall trying to figure it out.

I need to grab a value from a JSON response, but the key returned in the response is random, so I can't directly reference it to drill into it.

Here's the response I'm getting back:

```
var c = {
         "success": { 
                    "7d40ab5352b0471cae5bdefc2e032840": { 
                          "__type__" : "user",
                          "__id__" : "7d40ab5352b0471cae5bdefc2e032840"
                    }

         },
         "errors": {}
         }
```

What I need is the random string you see there - the ID. I've tried all kinds of things, and cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the ID back as a string. I've tried getting at it with array notation `c.success[0][0]` to no avail. Obviously, I can't use dot notation, since I don't know what to put after .success.

Anyone know what to do in a situation where the keys of the array aren't known beforehand? I want to make sure that I do this in a way that's considered the best practice, not a hack.

Thanks...and if I've somehow missed an answer to this that's otherwise published, please send me that way. I've searched for days and can't find this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var prop in c.success) {
  alert(c.success[prop].__id__); // Replace the alert with whatever you want to do with the ID
  // break; // Uncomment if there can be more than one ID returned and you only want one
}
```

and if the key is the same as the `__id__` value, you can simply do:

```
for (var prop in c.success) {
  alert(prop); // Replace the alert with whatever you want to do with the ID
  // break; // Uncomment if there can be more than one ID returned and you only want one
}
```

Although Šime Vidas's use of Object.keys is more elegant, you will need the above code to work in older browsers unless you use what is called a him (i.e., you add some extra code which lets you use new standards today--i.e., an implementation of Object.keys which does the same thing as I did above, unless a built-in version already exists, in which case the shim will give preference to the built-in version).

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
var obj = c.success[ Object.keys( c.success )[0] ];

obj.__type__ // "user"
obj.__id__ // "7d40ab5352b0471cae5bdefc2e032840"
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/AJaBS/

Comment: Oh, fancy! `Object.keys` indeed.

Comment: Elegant, but not backward-compatible

Comment: Holy crap ya'll are fast - this worked like charm, thanks so much!

Comment: So, Brett, I'll assume your answer is the more backward compatible one, since Object.keys is only available in modern browsers? Is there any big performance difference between the two?

Comment: @BrettZamir That's why we have ES5-shim, isn't it? `:P`

Comment: Shims are cool. But a bit of a pain to always remember to include, and then one has to update the shim code, etc. But yeah, that works (though I don't know if the user knows about how to add them)...

Comment: @BrettZamir Well, `for` and `for-in` loops don't cut it for me anymore. Now, we have ES5 array iteration methods and 3rd-party libraries provide their own implementations (e.g. jQuery's `$.each`). I wouldn't want to work in an environment where neither of those were allowed. That would be senseless and backward. So, either let me have jQuery (or an analogous library), or let me use ES5 API (by providing ES5-shim). Working with `for-in` loops has become to primitive, IMHO.

Comment: I agree for any project of substance. It's just good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop:

```
for (var id in c.success) {
    var obj = c.success[id];
    // do something
}
```

If you want to ensure that only the first property in the object will be handled, you can add a `break;` statement in the end.